# Manage workstations with Puppet and TheForeman

Tags: linux, puppet, configuration-management

I'm building an IT infrastructure for managing all the workstations in my company. I am interested in Puppet and a external node classifier as The Foreman, but I see all the time that Puppet and The Foreman is based for servers, is there any reason to not use Puppet and The Foreman for workstations? It is insane to manage about 1000 worksations or more with this configuration?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> is there any reason to not use Puppet and The Foreman for
>   workstations?

No

> It is insane to manage about 1000 worksations or more with this
>   configuration?

No